# Passing arrays to a class

Tags: c++, arrays

In this program I am trying to pass an array to my Player class but I keep getting an error

```
1>project.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall  Player::Player(int *
 const)" (??0Player@@QAE@QAH@Z) referenced in function _main
```

In the actual program I have the class itself in its own header file and I include it in my program. I then have another cpp file containing the definitions of the functions in the class player. This make sense? Anyways I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class Player
{
    public:

    void moveUp (); 

    void moveDown ();

    void moveRight ();

    void moveLeft ();

    Player(int b[16]); //create a variable to store the boardArray[]

};

void moveUp ()
{

}

void moveDown ()
{

}

void moveRight ()
{

}

void moveLeft ()
{

}

int drawBoard (int boardArray[16]) //draw the game board
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) //use a for loop to simply draw the game board (4x4)
    {
        cout <<boardArray[i]; //ouput the storage id of the array


        if ( i == 3 || i == 7 || i == 11 || i == 15) //every 4 lines begin new line
        {
            cout <<"\n";
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    int bArray[16] = { 1, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 0}; //create an array [16]
    drawBoard(bArray); //send the aray to drawBoard ()

    Player p (bArray); //send the array to the Player class


    char f;
    cin >>f;
}
```

Comment: That's not a variable, but a constructor. Variables are the same as they always are.

Comment: In your `Player` class you have a line that says: 
`Player(int b[16]);` which is trying to call the constructor for player, with an `int * const`, which is exactly what the error message is indicating.  I think you're meaning to call the constructor from elsewhere.  In either case, you need to define the constructor for `Player`.

Comment: you need `Player::Player`, `Player::moveUp`, etc. defined, when you define `moveUp` the compiler doesn't know you meant to associate that with `Player` unless you tell it by stating `Player::` before it.

Comment: I think you need to go back to your textbook -- you don't know some really basic stuff about how to define a class in C++.

Comment: What Glenn Teitelbaum said. Look up how to define classes in C++, such as this [site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) and let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: But how would I be able to assign something in my class to the bArray? @Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: The answer below may not ultimately be what you want your code to do, but it will give you a good starting point.

On this line, it is not doing what your comment states

```
Player(int b[16]); //create a variable to store the boardArray[]
```

What you have done is declared a constructor to take an array, but you haven't created it.  This declaration needs to be paired with an implementation, which I'll get to, but first you need to declare a member variable to store the array.

```
int mB[16];
```

Now you can implement your constructor, which I would insert just above `void moveUp()`

```
Player::Player(int b[])
{
    // copy b into the member array
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        mB[i] = b[i];
    }
}
```

Now you can use mB[] in your `move` functions without having to worry about b array going out of scope, basically meaning it's no longer valid and you can't rely on it's contents anymore.

Lastly, your constructor declaration doesn't need the [16] in the parameter list.  It should look like this

```
Player(int b[]);
```